# hide the orientation transition on safari ios

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari, orientation

i thought this would be an very frequent question, but i actually did not find any answer to it.

i am making a webapp/website for mobile.
When the user rotates his phone, i want to hide the whole body just before the page is rotated, with that ugly deformation/transition. Then, when this transition is done, show the body again.

[here](http://bastiengirschig.fr/test.html) i have done a minimal version of the code that works on android.
there is a background image from [loremPixel](http://lorempixel.com/) on the body, and a red background on the html tag.
the expected result is: never seing the image rotate. only a red screen (not rotating either)

thanks for any help.

***ps:** i think i have narrowed the problem down to the orientationchange event being fired **after** the rotation on ios, and **before**(as i would expect) on android*

Answer (score 0):

Random idea.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#wrapper").css("display","none");
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});

$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    $("#wrapper").css("display","block");
});
```

Start resize, hide wrapper.  No resize in 0.5 seconds, show.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ktg9can/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the delay. but the same problem occurs: the resize event is firing after the ugly transition i want to hide.

Comment: Oh well, worth a try.  Looks like maybe iOS is giving screen priority you can't capture until it's too late.  It's good to know of this "bug".  +1.